# Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Calling from API to API to a Sybase ASE DB

Tags: c#, json, http

I have two APIs the first, let's call it API1 calls API2 to get a list of stored procedures from a database by executing a stored procedure to query metadata (doubt that is important but putting it in for context.

API1 is .NET Core 3.1 and API2 is Framework 4.7.2 (not sure that matters either).

API2's controller is:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(DataTable))]
public DataTable GetListOfSprocNamesBySchema([FromBody]object sproc)
```

The calling code from API1 is:

```
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(schema), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiClient.ApiService.ApiClient.PostAsync(url, content);

      try
      {
          return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
```

If I call API2 directly with either of the following JSON bodies I get a success and receive a list of my sprocs as well as their IDs.

These are the schema objects for the above code:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "DBO",
    "databaseName": "PIM",
    "serverName": "FLUFFY"
}

{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "ADHOC",
    "databaseName": "QIS",
    "serverName": "ICKY"
}
```

However when I call "ICKY" through API1 (which calls API2) I get a success and data I expect. When I call "FLUFFY" through API1 (which calls API2) I get the following error:

> System.Exception: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable.
>   Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.
>   XXXXX Internal Server Error XXXXX Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma:
>   no-cache Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2020 15:57:08 GMT  XXXXX
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent XXXXX Method: POST,
>   RequestUri: '.../api/MetaData/GetListOfSprocNamesBySchema', Version:
>   1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers: {   Accept: application/json   Request-Id: |47e1e80-468fc91067c479f3.5.
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8   Content-Length: 78 }

Both calls use the exact same path through the two APIs... only difference is from which database they get their information ("ICKY" hits Sybase IQ all 3 of my problem children hit Sybase ASE if that makes a difference). All of these calls when I call API2 directly retrieve something like this:

```
[
    {
        "procedureID": 4419,
        "procedureName": "AccountsSameEmail"
    },
    {
        "procedureID": 4173,
        "procedureName": "AccountsToGoal"
    }
]
```

There are like 1k+ sprocs depending on which schema/DB you hit but they all return like that in format.

Judging by the error I assumed it was a formatting error on the JSON constructed by the controller on the return from API2 however if that were the case I would have expected ALL the returns to be an issue not just 3 of 4 permutations.

I need a way to see what the communication between the two APIs keeping in mind that our security here is rather Orwellian so fun 3rd party tools are completely out... I have Resharper and that is about it besides Pro VS2019.

Is there a way to see what the body is on the call? All I see everywhere I look is Header information and byte[] and length.

Comment: Is that error from the logs of API2 or is that the failure as returned from the call to API2 (it's occuring on API1)?

Comment: @MikeJ That was from the call... and I think I might have been just stupid checking my commits to DevOps it has been a learning experience.

Comment: Ok, so it would appear that my commits all match, seems I might have an issue with the dev box talking to ASE which I would have liked a nicer error message of that were the case.

Answer (score 0):

So in my instance it turns out 3 things happened.

My IQ driver when we got it from the on premises ProGit that security manages does not show the correct version number. There is a "silent 4" at the end of it which one of my colleagues found only through a powershell script against the ProGit.

My ASE driver, even after I corrected it two weeks ago, was still referencing a local share instead of the nuget. This was likely an issue with a stale build/commit so this is something I will be more diligent about tracking from here on out.

Finally, the version numbers changed on Dev and ProGit and I didn't have an acceptable range designation (although I forget how to do that but will find it and implement to prevent future issues).

This isn't the first time versioning has bitten me in the arse probably won't be the last either, but the error message this kicked out was very confusing and misleading.